# Irreducible action of an algebraic group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Is the following claim true?:

Let $G$ be an algebraic group such that $G^\circ$ is reductive. Suppose $G$ acts irreducibly on $V$. Is it true that $V$ is decomposed (written as direct sum) into $G^\circ$ components of equal dimension?

Comment: I don't think equal dimension implies isotypic in general.  Which one do you want?

Comment: I mean equal dimension: Decompose in to irreducible components of equal dimension.

Comment: It is true: take any irreducible $G^0$ submodule $W$ of the irreducible $G$-module $V$; then $V$ is the sum of $g(W)$ for $g\in G$. Hence we have a surjection from the direct sum of $g(W)$ onto $V$. This means that $V$ is a direct sum of irreps of the same dimension. Of course, isotypical is false.

Comment: @Venkataramana: How to explain this ?: Let $G$ be a finite group, and $V$ be a finite dimensional irreducible representation of $G$. Then pick some vector of $V$ and use the elements of $G$ to span $V$. Does it follow that $V$ is a DIRECT SUM?

Comment: of course; as a rep of the trivial group, $V$ is a direct sum of one dimensional trivial representations of the trivial group

Comment: May be I didn't know how to put it clearly. Thanks for your prompt response Sir. I was analyzing as follows: $G$ is the disjoint union of $G^\circ$ and its translates $g_1G^\circ,\ldots, g_n G^\circ$. Let $W$ be some $G^\circ$-irreducible component. Then, since $g_i(W)$ is stabilized by $G^\circ$ (because $G^\circ . g_i (W) = g_i g_i^{-1} G^\circ g_i (W) = g_i( W)$  ), $g_i(W)$ is $G^\circ$-irreducible SUBSPACE of $V$. Therefore, $V = W + g_1(W) + \ldots + g_n(W)$. But I am not sure how to see the direct sum. Thank you.

Comment: Why does not $V$ decompose into isotypic components?

Comment: Itis easy to see that if $V$ is any (say finite dimensional ) module over a group $H$ which is a sum $\sum W_i$ of irreducible $H$ modules $W_i$, then $V$ is a direct sum of irreducibles. To see this, let $W$ be an $H$ subspace of $V$ which is of the largest dimension, which is a direct sum of irreducibles; then $W\neq 0$ since $W$ contains one of the $W_i$. If some $W_j$ does not lie in $W$, then $W+W_j$ is the direct sum of $W$ and $W_j$, since $W_j$ is irreducible; this contradicts maximality of $W$ and hence $W=V$.

Comment: Take the standard representation $V$ of $G=N(T)$ the normalizer of $T$, the group of diagonals in $GL(V)$. Then $V$ is irreducible for $G$; as a rep of $G^0=T$, $V$ decomposes as a direct sum of one dimensional distinct characters.

Comment: @Venkataramana: Thank you very much for your detailed description Sir.

Comment: @Venkataramana, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181754/irreducible-action-of-an-algebraic-group/448179#comment455875_181754), I think it's a little more subtle: $G$ might not have enough rational points to make a sum over $G(k)$ stable under $G$, so I think you have to do something like sum over $G(k^\text{sep})$, then group the summands minimally to form $\operatorname{Gal}(k^\text{sep}/k)$-stable representations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and even in much more generality. This is a direct application of Clifford's Theorem, which I believe works for any group $G$ acting irreducibly on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, with a reductive normal subgroup $N$ of finite index (in this case, $N = G^{0}$). Indeed, the proof given by others in the comments is one of the usual module-theoretic proofs of Clifford's Theorem, e.g. the one on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_theory#Proof_of_Clifford%27s_theorem).

(As to why it's not necessarily isotypic as an $N$-module, asked as a follow-up in the comments. The $N$-irreps appearing can be twisted-equivalent to one another, twisted by an automorphism of $N$ coming from the conjugation action of $G$ on $N$.)

Comment: The problem does not require that $V$ be finite dimensional.  Also, Clifford theory as usually stated is for representations of abstract groups and their finite-index subgroups.  It probably works just fine over an infinite field $k$ with $G(k) \to \pi_0(G)(k)$ surjective because of Zariski density of $G(k)$  in $G$, but I wouldn't be completely confident of that, or that things can't fail for $G$ with "irrational components" or over finite fields.

Comment: I assumed that "algebraic group" meant G was finite-dimensional and that $G/G^0$ was finite. And then doesn't it follow that any irrep of $G^0$, and hence $G$, is finite-dimensional? But re: other fields, yes, I see there is potentially an issue for non-algebraically closed fields.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181754/irreducible-action-of-an-algebraic-group/448179#comment1163383_448179), yes, I agree about representations of $G^\circ$, and hence about representations of $G$ if some analogue of Clifford theory works, so I guess it's just that same objection again.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181754/irreducible-action-of-an-algebraic-group/448179#comment1163383_448179), also, now that I think about it, as long as the case where $G(k) \to \pi_0(G)(k)$ is surjective works, *and* as long as every irreducible representation of $G$ decomposes into finitely many components on passage to $k^\text{sep}$, I guess everything is probably fine by Galois descent.  (But I haven't thought carefully.)